# add users with login on phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, authentication

Hello I am creating an app for phonegap on android and I wanted to see how I can make a user login section.  This section should let them register with a username and password and enter their email or just login if they already have a username .  Also do I need a website to hold all of this data?

Thanks!

Comment: Log in to gain access to what resources?  Those entirely local to the application, or to functionality, data, or pay-metering on an external server?

Comment: to be able to log in and view photos online held under their username

Answer (score 0):

you need to try things before coming to SO.

BUT to point you in the right direction.

1) create a simple restFUL API that lets people sign up

2) use Local storage to store that info on the users phone

3) each time the app launches, do an ajax request to your server with the localstorage username and password

4) Let user do what ever.

It's really quite a simple process - as for your hosting question depending on what you see usage being... if your app is going to be getting a lot of traffic you should consider a cloud based solution. Amazon will let you quickly scale the app and automatically take care of load balancing, Heroku is also pretty good at this. On the fly scaling as well.. Lastly getting a host like Bluehost is a good option - flexibility, and reliability - also a good price.